# Permalink structure forcing child site to parent site domain

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, multisite

I have a multi-domain multisite on WordPress. I didn´t like the /blog slug on parent site so I followed these simple steps:

1. At blog site set Settings -> Permalinks -> Common Setting -> Default
2. At Network Admin -> Sites -> (root site) Permalink Sturcture -> /%category%/%post_id%

Now the /blog slug is gone, but I can only use default permalink structure with child site, because other permalink structures will change all child site links to parent site url.

How can I fix it to be able to use all permalink structures? (domain is mapped and working well with default permalink structure)

Comment: Can you take your time and rephrase your post so as to making it clearer? As it stands, it's difficult to tell what your current challenge and desire result are.

Comment: I rephrased it a bit - the main problem is that when I use other than default permalink structure with child site, WP forces it to have parent site domain - .cz not .sk

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Somehow the reason for malfunction was activated Polylang plugin. Workaround to get rid of /blog slug was not the reason.